# Getting Twirl to stream a scala template render output?

Tags: java, playframework

Using Play Framework with Java (controller) and Twirl, I am trying to send a page that contains about 40MB of data to the caller, through a single HTTP GET request (using scala templates, nothing special here). The issue is that when I call the render method on the template, my application crashes with an OutOfMemoryError. I am 100% positive it is relative to page weigth VS available heap memory, I have confirmed it through testing. I think it is related to the fact that "To be able to compute the Content-Length header properly, Play must consume the whole response data and load its content into memory." (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaStream). The Twirl templates render method seems to load the entire page into memory just the same anyway.

I have confirmed, as mentionned in the docs, that if I use an InputStream to output my own data, things will work smoothly and I can send as much data as I want (up to gigabytes of data if I want, it just works) back to the client simply by returning *ok(myInputStream)* in my controller method.

Now, what I would like to do is to get Twirl to render its template using streaming (providing me an InputStream or something similar). I have searched for solutions, read the docs to no avail. Am I looking at the wrong places, or it is just not available and possible by design, and I have no other choices than to rethink my template and requests/responses ?

Java 8, Play Framework 2.5.